# R: how to resample intraday data at the group level?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, lubridate

Consider the following dataframe

```
time <-c('2016-04-13 23:07:45','2016-04-13 23:07:50','2016-04-13 23:08:45','2016-04-13 23:08:45'
         ,'2016-04-13 23:08:45','2016-04-13 23:07:50','2016-04-13 23:07:51')
group <-c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B')
value<- c(5,10,2,2,NA,1,4)
df<-data.frame(time,group,value)

> df
                 time group value
1 2016-04-13 23:07:45     A     5
2 2016-04-13 23:07:50     A    10
3 2016-04-13 23:08:45     A     2
4 2016-04-13 23:08:45     B     2
5 2016-04-13 23:08:45     B    NA
6 2016-04-13 23:07:50     B     1
7 2016-04-13 23:07:51     B     4
```

I would like to **resample** this dataframe at the `5 seconds level` - `group level`, and compute the **sum** of `value` for each `time-interval` - `group value`.

**The interval should be closed on the left and open on the right**. For instance, the first line of output should be

`2016-04-13 23:07:45     A     5` because the first 5-sec interval is `[2016-04-13 23:07:45, 2016-04-13 23:07:50[`

How can I do that in either `dplyr` or `data.table`? Do I need to import `lubridate` for the timestamps?

Comment: typos fixed. many thanks!

Comment: I think `foverlaps` from `data.table` could be of use in this case. I'll see if I can bake an asnwer

Comment: thanks, or maybe with a `dplyr` `group_by` ? I have no clue

Comment: @Noobie, just for clarification, I'm guessing the interval is open on the right... (this is why you don't include the `23:07:50` value in the sum of the first line of output)? Also, what do you do with the groups if they are different but occur in the same time interval (e.g. `7 2016-04-13 23:07:51     B     4` and let's say the next line was `8 2016-04-13 23:07:53     A     12`)? Do we ignore the difference in groups and simply sum 1, 4, and 12?

Comment: Hi Joseph yes, closed on left and open on right. For the second points, the aggregation is at the time-group level, so two exact timestamps for two different groups will never be mixed up together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(dplyr)
Group5 <- function(myDf) {
    myDf$time <- ymd_hms(myDf$time)
    myDf$timeGroup <- floor_date(myDf$time, unit = "5 seconds")
    summarise(myDf %>% group_by(group, timeGroup), sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
}

Group5(df)
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
Groups: group [?]

   group           timeGroup `sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)`
  <fctr>              <dttm>                      <dbl>
1      A 2016-04-13 23:07:45                          5
2      A 2016-04-13 23:07:50                         10
3      A 2016-04-13 23:08:45                          2
4      B 2016-04-13 23:07:50                          5
5      B 2016-04-13 23:08:45                          2
```

It takes advantage of `floor_date` and `ymd_hms` from `lubridate` to put each date time into the proper group-time.

Here is a more exotic example:

```
set.seed(500)
time <- ymd_hms('2016-04-13 23:07:45') + sample(-10^3:10^3, 10^5, replace=TRUE)
group <- rep(LETTERS[1:20], each = 5000)
value <- rep(NA, 10^5)
value[sample(10^5, 95000)] <- sample(100, 95000, replace=TRUE)
df2 <- data.frame(time,group,value)

head(df2)
                 time group value
1 2016-04-13 23:18:53     A    53
2 2016-04-13 23:15:15     A    NA
3 2016-04-13 23:23:36     A    40
4 2016-04-13 23:06:40     A    23
5 2016-04-13 23:18:10     A    74
6 2016-04-13 22:57:56     A    65
```

Calling it we have:

```
Group5(df2)
Source: local data frame [8,020 x 3]
Groups: group [?]

    group           timeGroup `sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)`
   <fctr>              <dttm>                      <int>
1       A 2016-04-13 22:51:05                        379
2       A 2016-04-13 22:51:10                        646
3       A 2016-04-13 22:51:15                        391
4       A 2016-04-13 22:51:20                       1118
5       A 2016-04-13 22:51:25                        745
6       A 2016-04-13 22:51:30                        546
7       A 2016-04-13 22:51:35                        884
8       A 2016-04-13 22:51:40                        711
9       A 2016-04-13 22:51:45                        526
10      A 2016-04-13 22:51:50                        484
# ... with 8,010 more rows
```

Comment: Nice guess from Op's question, didn't though about rounding on the 5 sec interval.

Answer (score 6):

With latest version (1.9.8+) of `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

# convert to data.table, fix time, add future time
setDT(df)
df[, time := as.POSIXct(time)][, time.5s := time + 5]

# use non-equi join to filter on the required intervals and sum
df[, newval := df[df, on = .(group, time < time.5s, time >= time),
                  sum(value, na.rm = T), by = .EACHI]$V1]
df
#                  time group value             time.5s newval
#1: 2016-04-13 23:07:45     A     5 2016-04-13 23:07:50      5
#2: 2016-04-13 23:07:50     A    10 2016-04-13 23:07:55     10
#3: 2016-04-13 23:08:45     A     2 2016-04-13 23:08:50      2
#4: 2016-04-13 23:08:45     B     2 2016-04-13 23:08:50      2
#5: 2016-04-13 23:08:45     B    NA 2016-04-13 23:08:50      2
#6: 2016-04-13 23:07:50     B     1 2016-04-13 23:07:55      5
#7: 2016-04-13 23:07:51     B     4 2016-04-13 23:07:56      4
```

Comment: very nice. do you think the next version of `data.table` will support alternative opening/closing schemes? say closed on the right, closed on the left for instance?

Comment: Simply change the inequalities in `on` from strict to not strict as needed.

Comment: shouldn't 6 and 7 be grouped together?  They are in the same 5 second interval. It looks like you are simply adding 5 seconds to each result.

Comment: true. 6 and 7 should be summed together. nice catch @JosephWood

Comment: #7 is in #6's future interval, but #6 is not in #7's future interval.. if you're looking for a future+past match, add a `time.neg.5s := time - 5` column and compare with that

Comment: I've the feeling time and time.5s can be created in the same call, but I'm unsure this would improve speed in anyway

Comment: @Tensibai `setDT(df)
microbenchmark({df1 <- copy(df); df1[, time := as.POSIXct(time)][, time.5s := time + 5]},
               {df2 <- copy(df); df2[, c('time', 'time.5s')  := list(time1 <- as.POSIXct(time), time1 + 5)]}, times = 300)` suggests df2 (create all in one call) is faster

Comment: @FXQuantTrader yeah, by a **milli**second

Answer (score 2):

Best idea I came to with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, result:={lv=df$group==group; dt=difftime( df$time, time, units="sec"); print(dt); sum(df$value[lv & dt >= 0 & dt < 5],na.rm=TRUE)},by=1:nrow(df)]
```

Output:

```
                  time group value result
1: 2016-04-13 23:07:45     A     5      5
2: 2016-04-13 23:07:50     A    10     10
3: 2016-04-13 23:08:45     A     2      2
4: 2016-04-13 23:08:45     B     2      2
5: 2016-04-13 23:08:45     B    NA      2
6: 2016-04-13 23:07:50     B     1      5
7: 2016-04-13 23:07:51     B     4      4
```

The `j` part in details:

```
lv=df$group==group # Create a logical vector to filter at end
dt=abs( difftime( df$time, time, units="sec")) # compute the time difference in seconds between current row and all others
 sum(df$value[lv & dt >= 0 & dt < 5]) # Sum the values where in same group and the difference in seconds is between 0 and 5 secs, 0 included, 5 excluded
```

the `result:={}` allow us to create the result as a function call. the `by=1:nrow(df)` makes it work row by row.

And to filter the resulting to get the starting point only:

```
> df[,.SD[!duplicated(result)],by=group]
   group                time value result
1:     A 2016-04-13 23:07:45     5      5
2:     A 2016-04-13 23:07:50    10     10
3:     A 2016-04-13 23:08:45     2      2
4:     B 2016-04-13 23:08:45     2      2
5:     B 2016-04-13 23:07:50     1      5
6:     B 2016-04-13 23:07:51     4      4
```

Comment: Why is your `result` for row 7 equal to 5? The previous row is not in the range `[time, time+5)`.

Comment: @eddi row 6 is in the range within 5 seconds, if not wanted just remove the abs call around difftime

Comment: @Eddie, I extrapolated from Op's Q about the range, indeed the abs call is superfluous for the answer in this case

Comment: @Tensibai, not sure if this is a question or suggestion... should we be removing NAs when summing?

Comment: Also, you need to change `data.frame` to `data.table`.. it took me a couple of times getting errors before I realized that I needed `data.table`.

Comment: @Joseph my bad, typed frame instead of table on first line :/ sorry, and forgot the setDT call in the code also

Comment: @Joseph about NA,  on first thought I won't, but I assume only OP can answer it :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to have separate data objects for each group, you could use `xts` to solve your problem instead of `data.table`, per group object.  xts `period.apply` will automatically handle your interval being closed on the left side but open on the right too (which is really helpful for aggregating financial tick data to bar frequencies.  You wont get double counting of ticks on interval edges for consecutive bars/intervals):

```
time <-c('2016-04-13 23:07:45','2016-04-13 23:07:55','2016-04-13 23:08:45','2016-04-13 23:08:45'
         ,'2016-04-13 23:08:45','2016-04-13 23:07:50','2016-04-13 23:07:51')
group <-c('A','A','A','B','B','B','B')

value<- c(5,10,2,2,NA,1,4)
df=data.frame(time,group,value)

library(quantmod)
library(lubridate)
df$time = ymd_hms(df$time)

# In this example, model group B object: (You can easily generalise this with a loop or lapply over multiple groups)
df_grp <- df[df$group == "B", ]
x.df_grp <- xts(df_grp$value, order.by = df_grp$time) 
ep <- endpoints(x.df_grp, on = "seconds", k = 5)
# You can replace sum by any useful function.  Pass in extra arguments to period.apply that correspond to FUN, here na.rm = T, to avoid having sum returning NA in your group B row:
x.df_grp_5sec <- period.apply(x.df_grp, ep, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
# Align timestamps to end of each 5 sec interval by default (helps avoid lookforward bias when merging time series data on different time frequencies):
x.df_grp_5sec <- align.time(x.df_grp_5sec, 5)
# Now record timestamps at start of each 5 sec interval:
.index(x.df_grp_5sec) <- .index(x.df_grp_5sec) - 5

#result:
> x.df_grp_5sec
                    [,1]
2016-04-13 23:07:50    5
2016-04-13 23:08:45    2
```