# R data.table rolling join weird behaviour with the rolling column

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following rolling join:

```
require(data.table)

dtx = data.table(name.x = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), time.x = c(2, 4, 6, 8), info.x = c(2, 4, 6, 8))
dti = data.table(name.i = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), time.i = c(1, 3, 5, 7), info.i = c(1, 3, 5, 7))

dtz = dtx[dti, list(name.i = name.i, name.x = name.x, time.i = time.i, time.x = time.x, info.i = info.i, info.x = info.x),
    on = c(name.x = "name.i", time.x = "time.i"), roll = -1]
print(dtz)
#   name.i name.x time.i time.x info.i info.x
#1:      a      a      1      1      1      2
#2:      a      a      3      3      3      4
#3:      b      b      5      5      5      6
#4:      b      b      7      7      7      8
```

All the columns make sense, except the time.x column. I would have expected it to contain the values 2,4,6,8. In fact the values 1,3,5,7 are not even present in dtx.

Clearly time.x has been replaced with time.i, and it has been done in a manner so as to express the NOCB (next observation carried forward) logic as a regular join.

I'm just wondering if this is expected behaviour, that we will lose the time.x column? Since it is not mentioned in the documentation for rolls, and is breaking the concordance between rolls and regular joins.

(I'm using data.table 1.9.6 btw)

Comment: Fyi, `j` in `x[i, j]` will automatically allow prefixes `i.*` and `x.*` to refer to respective columns, whether names conflict or not. Also, I guess you can write your `on` and `j` more concisely if you want. (This may all require 1.9.8, released recently. I'm not sure.)

Comment: Ah, I didnt know that x.* existed. And if I understand you right, both i.* and x.* can be used in 'on' (apart from j). Cool, thanks.

Comment: I think in `on`, the left-hand side is always the name in `x`, while the right is in `i`. This can get kind of confusing once you're using "non-equi joins" and writing things like `on=.(id, time >= time)`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39920839/ I don't think `x.*` and `i.*` are available in `on` but never tried it.

Comment: Oh sorry. Your first comment clearly mentioned `x.*` is for use in `j`. Thanks. I too use named vectors for `on`.